# Cardano-Node having errors at 84% sync

Tags: cardano-node

- cardano-node 1.35.5
- linux-x86_64
- ghc-8.10
- git rev 8762a10efe3f9f97939e3cb05edaf04250456702
- Trying to connect to testnet

I downloaded the binary and configured it per instructions at lovelace academy.  I left it running as it was syncing successfully until it got to around 84%, then it stopped making progress and instead keeps spitting out errors and warnings based around "invalid block"

Some errors:

```
[Computer:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:3207] [2023-02-02 03:26:52.54 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 3.131.32.242:3001 InvalidBlock (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 63419662, blockPointHash = 38dc2f5dbb184b504eda086a5f64c19931a985bf2246b74ed18e796712cff67a})) 708745ea94515b679223a5514e6e6dba068208e5b79780134206f74e1e79e727 (ValidationError (ExtValidationErrorLedger (HardForkLedgerErrorFromEra S (S (S (S (S (Z (WrapLedgerErr {unwrapLedgerErr = BBodyError (BlockTransitionError [ShelleyInAlonzoPredFail (LedgersFailure (LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (MalformedScriptWitnesses (fromList [ScriptHash "eee7bfb25cfbbbcd31a1d5d648429ff919430ee5d06d8d056e48d605"])))))])})))))))))

[Computer:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:81] [2023-02-02 03:26:52.54 UTC] IP 3.131.32.242:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (InvalidBlock (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 63419662, blockPointHash = 38dc2f5dbb184b504eda086a5f64c19931a985bf2246b74ed18e796712cff67a})) 708745ea94515b679223a5514e6e6dba068208e5b79780134206f74e1e79e727 (ValidationError (ExtValidationErrorLedger (HardForkLedgerErrorFromEra S (S (S (S (S (Z (WrapLedgerErr {unwrapLedgerErr = BBodyError (BlockTransitionError [ShelleyInAlonzoPredFail (LedgersFailure (LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (MalformedScriptWitnesses (fromList [ScriptHash "eee7bfb25cfbbbcd31a1d5d648429ff919430ee5d06d8d056e48d605"])))))])})))))))))))) 200s 200s

[Computer:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:85] [2023-02-02 03:27:12.21 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Unsupported remote target address [2600:1f1c:d4f:6d00:0:1:0:4]:3001
```

It keep repeating these and other warnings over and over again.  I don't know how to fix the "Invalidblock" situation.  I tried rebooting but that didn't help.  Is there a way I can delete the invalid block or ledger entry, or delete all the synced data and try again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it should be possible to fully sync `testnet` with recent versions of cardano node. There was a divergence in ledger rules last year. For this reason, it is deprecated and no one should be using it.

Look at using either `preview` or `preprod` testnets. Config files can be found here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm syncing from genesis using 1.35.5 , currently at 27%. Will let you know how it goes.

The Cardano block chain DB is stored in state-node-mainnet directory or state-node-testnet dir if syncing testnet in the cardano-node root directory.

If you need to resync from genesis:

1. Stop the node
2. Delete the state-node- directory of corresponding network
3. Start the node again syncing from scratch

Answer (score -1):

try this amazing tool :)
they take snapshot of the db
https://csnapshots.io/about

How does it work

- Every day they are generating new snapshots and uploading to CDN service which redistributes the database to servers around the world for faster download speeds